# How to handle \r\n from command output in python or bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, newline

I am running a simple bash script

`var=$(script.sh)`

the output of `script.sh` is of the form:

```
\r\n

123

ok
```

Now when I do:

`echo $var` it returns `\r\n`. It has not captured the `123` and `ok`. I want `var` to get the entire output.

In python I tried the same thing using:

```
bashCommand = ./myscript.sh

process = Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output, error = process.communicate()

print("Output", output)
```

but even here print output prints `\r\n`

How to capture the entire `stdout`?
**Update:**

here's my bash script `xyz.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -x

./myscript.elf parm1 parm2 |{
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done
}
```

Heres the output of `./xyz.sh`:

```
+ ./myscript.elf parm1 parm2
+ IFS=
+ read -r line

>123
OK
>+ echo $'\r'

+ IFS=
+ read -r line
```

Here is the output if just run the command on `./myscript.elf parm1 parm2` line:

```
./myscript.elf parm1 parm2

>123
OK
>
```

Comment: Is the other stuff actually being printed to stdout and not stderr?

Comment: I ran `echo $var` and got `123 ok`. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: When you say `\r\n`, do you mean backslash r backslash n, or carriagereturn linefeed?

Comment: its the carriagereturn linefeed. bash thinks its reached the end of command and stops at the first line.

Comment: I wonder if the command line is adding a new line or if it's actually your program. Try piping first to a file and then using `xxd` to analyze the hex to determine whether or not a new line is actually in there.

Comment: what happens when you use `echo "$var"` (note the dbl-quotes surrounding `$var` ;-) ) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's partly because of the IFS, and the lousy output.

An example workaround:

```
 script.sh > /tmp/file.log
 var=""
 while IFS= read -r line ;do
     [ -z "$line" ] && continue
     var="$line $var"
 done < "${file}"
 echo "$var"
```

basically output to a file, then read the file and take in the data you really need .. etc ..  PS> your question /code is hard to follow this is best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like myscript.elf is sending most of its output to standard error rather than standard output; thus, neither `$( )` nor piping it to a `while read` loop capture it, it just goes straight to the terminal. If you want to merge the error output into the standard output, append `2>&1` to the command, like this:

```
var=$(myscript.elf 2>&1)
```

or

```
./myscript.elf parm1 parm2 2>&1 | while read -r line
```

BTW, having carriage returns in your variables (and files) tends to cause confusion, so you might want to remove them with something like this:

```
var=$(myscript.elf 2>&1 | tr -d '\r')
```